# How to display names and title of two persons who participated in the meeting the most

Tags: sql

I have to display names and title of two persons who participated in the most meeting together in the following format :-

[image: output]

Tables are :

[image: Table person]

[image: Table meeting]

[image: Table participant]

My code:-

```
select pe1.name as Person1,
       pe2.name as Person2,
       count(1) as SharedMeetings
from participant pa1
join participant pa2
  on  pa2.idMeeting = pa1.idMeeting
  and pa2.idPerson > pa1.idPerson
join person pe1
  on pe1.id = pa1.idPerson
join person pe2
  on pe2.id = pa2.idPerson
group by pe1.name,
         pe2.name
order by SharedMeetings desc,
         pe1.name,
         pe2.name;
```

Output : [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHKFB.png)

I am not able to get output in desired format as mentioned in first line.
How do I do that. Please help!

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the sample data as text. Please read [Why not upload images when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Abra How do i write my tables and output!!!???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I presume that you can copy paste the displayed table data as text. Don't use a [snipping tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b). Also, I suggest that you read [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I'm confused.  Your question is about the names of two people.  Your results also show the meetings in common.  Which do you really want?